# Use Javascript to return as a php variable

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not sure if this is possible since javascript is client side and php is server side, but what I have is a series of javascript functions that give a real time total to orders in a form. To clarify that, as the user selects items in the form it gives a total. On submission of the form php is submitting the order to the database. What I need to achieve is a way to submit the total (created by javascript) of the order to the database (via php obv). The javascript function that creates the total is:

```
function calculateTotal(){
     var Price = getDropPrice() + getverifyPrice() + getmiscPrice();
     var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
     divobj.style.display='block';
     divobj.innerHTML = "$"+Price;
}
```

The html where this is produced is pretty simple:

```
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

If you need me to post the other `functions(getDropPrice, getverifyPrice, getmiscPrice)` let me know, but basically drop is a drop down, verify and misc are radio buttons, I'm just adding their totals together to get the order total in the function above. My searches on SO and google have only shown me how to get php variables into javascript not the other way around so I certainly hope this can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your total in hidden input field. Then your PHP script will be able to read after the form is submited and do whatever you want.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" />
```

and then you get it as usual form `$_POST['hiddenInput']`; If you got more data to send back that way, you may either add more inputs, or stick to one but pack your all data into JSON and send that way. Once received, you do `json_decode()` on that field and you got it all back, no matter how many data was sent.

I, however would **NOT** recommend relying on user side provided data and rather send back which products are selected and calculate totals again, otherwise you may find yourself selling expensive goods for $1 one day :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your answer seems to be the easiest way but would you think toxicate20's answer below would solve the issue that you mention?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The issue is that anything coming from JavaScript is, by definition, coming from the client, which makes it trivial to spoof. If you let the client-side code determine how much the client should be paying, nothing is stopping the client from deciding that he wants to pay a penny. Golden rule of programming: NEVER TRUST USER INPUT. That goes a hundred times when you're handling money. Instead, just get the list of things they want, and then calculate the price on the server where it can't be meddled with.

Comment: Thanks General, that makes sense. Right now I just need the form to function, there are a few security concerns that need to be addressed on the site, and as bad of a practice as it may be I'll need to address those after the initial release, but that does make sense and I'll certainly keep it in mind! Thanks again.

Comment: Somewhere I am making a mistake here, the code I'm using to create the hidden field is this `<script>document.write("<input type='hidden' name='totalamount' id='totalamount' value='"+Price+"'>");</script>` However this isn't working, my php is all correct.

Comment: I have to agree with @General_Mayhem. You should always recalculate the value on the server rather than trust any calculations done on the client. Client side calculations are convenient and fast but not trustworthy

Comment: @Nathan: This isn't a minor security problem. This is putting all of your products outside in a seedy part of town and then leaving the store unattended while you go to lunch. It's a fundamental problem that can literally be broken in under a minute with no tools other than the Web browser used to load your site in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is $.ajax from jQuery. This will send a POST request without reloading the page.

Lets say your button is called myButton then for the onClick() event you would call the function

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).success(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

In your some.php you would then just use $_POST['name'] and $_POST['location'] to retrieve the information.

Suppose you had an input field. You can retrieve information from such a field via jQuery as well. You can just then send the information from the input field via ajax to you php script

```
$('#yourInputField').val();
```

where yourInputField is the ID of the input field. With this you can get this information to the script. If you have multiple elements in a form you might want to look at the function serialize(). Does the same thing in principle, just compresses all the information into a JSON string.

Comment: As an additional note, it's also better to send a session ID with the POST request, as otherwise it might be prone to SQL injection from this page. So using PHP and sessions, make a session variable with a chain of random letters and numbers, then echo that chain into the JS code and send it with the `POST` request. Then on the PHP page, retrieve the sent code and compare it with the stored code in the `SESSION` array.

Comment: for the url the php is on the same page, for the form I solve this with `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` can i do the same with jquery?

Comment: Of course, you can do the same (just make sure the jQuery is on the same page and not in an external file). Also make sure to compare a value in PHP to verify that it's not the user loading the page but the JS making an Ajax request.

Comment: @MrXenotype: That's all really quite silly. Security in JavaScript is a contradiction in terms. Using nonces so that only your site's page can make the request makes no difference in a world where arbitrary code can be run on the page in the browser console; you still absolutely have to be verifying/recalculating values on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is why the authors made the `"input"` element with type of `"hidden"`. Use one of them and set the `"value"` attribute of the element to the total amount that you want, then post your form to the database and you can simply access the hidden value like the other values on the form.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="TotalPrice_Input" />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("TotalPrice_Input").value = Price;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mix Javascript with PHP:

```
<?php
$mixit = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$mixit .= 'function calculateTotal() {';
$mixit .= 'var Price = getDropPrice() + getverifyPrice() + getmiscPrice();';
$mixit .= 'var divobj = document.getElementById("totalPrice");';
$mixit .= 'divobj.style.display="block";';
$mixit .= 'divobj.innerHTML = '.$Price.';}';
$mixit .= '</script>';


echo $mixit;

?>
```